# Installing TorChat on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, installation, github, deb

I Have a problem with installing Torchat on my Kali Linux 
this is my version 
Linux ******* 4.18.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2kali1 (2018-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux.

In the Github site I downloaded Torchat but in the site it says that I need :The .deb package depends on python (>= 2.5, << 3.0) and python-wxgtk2.8 (aka wxPython) and tor.but I don't have python-wxgtk2.8 I have python-wxgtk3 and python3 so when I dpkg Torchat it says:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of torchat:torchat depends on python-wxgtk2.8; however:Package python-wxgtk2.8 is not installed.
besides I can't install python-wxgtk2.8
Help plz I need torchat to talk with someone

Comment: Simplest solution is to use a proper distro. Kali is for *penetration testing*, not for installing services like Torchat. No, Kali is not "what all the cool hackers use", no matter what you read on some forums. Please also read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me). Kali is well known to have trouble with standard packages. Just use something Debian-based instead.

Comment: @dirkt I heard somewhere that Kali was Debian-based now... but there are dozens of Debian-based distros to choose from, some definitely much *much* ***much*** easier to use than Kali. [TorChat's in Debian stable](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/torchat), there's no excuse it shouldn't work on a decent Debian. @ Bradass_FaLLaG do you have Debian repositories enabled? Can Kali even do that? Where'd you get the package you're trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use apt? Just type in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install torchat
```

Comment: /home/user# sudo apt-get install torchat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package torchat